# Template cannot be resolved for Typesafe Activator in Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, playframework, typesafe-activator

I downloaded the latest Typesafe activator-1.0.10. I unzipped the zip and started the activator in UI mode.
Now when I try to create an application using the template Hello Play Framework (Java Only), the activator fails with a message as below:

> [ERROR] [12/29/2013 21:46:58.224] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akk
>   a://default/user/template-cache] Failed to resolve template: 11bc7a19-fdd2-4225-
>   9156-c8d2bee46f44 from remote repository.

I tried downloading the template bundle and run the activator from within the bundle, the activator ui doesnot come up at all.
Is this an issue with Windows 8, or am I missing some configuration?
Please help.

Comment: It sounds like the template server can't be reached for some reason.  Do you have a proxy server?  Also this sounds like a bug so can you file it: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/new

Comment: have u tried to create in command line mode..just type activator new <app name> and follows with template name...?

Comment: @James Ward: I have raised a issue #225 - 
Template cannot be resolved for Typesafe Activator in Windows 8.
It seems to be a Windows 8 issue, as the exact same distribution works perfectly in my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved with the latest Activator: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/225

Download it: http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted